# Materialize: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollSpy is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, scrollspy

I am using the [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) framework, and for the life of me can not figure out why the scrollspy plugin is not working for me. My markup or css certainly isn't the issue - I'm certain it's right.

Console is showing:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollSpy is not a function

And references the line where I initialize the plugin:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.scrollspy').scrollSpy();
});
```

I was under the impression that the plugin "came with" materialize's JS, but even when I include scrollspy.js myself in my header, I'm still getting the error.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you try replacing $ with jQuery

Comment: Is the `<script>` tag for materialize/scrollspy below the `<script>` tag for jQuery?

Comment: If `$` refers to jQuery, and so it isn't your issue, you are maybe loading jQuery more than once

Comment: Please show your `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm totally blind – @A.Wolff was right – I'd mistakenly loaded jQuery (different versions at that) twice.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.9">
  <title>{% if page.title %}{{ page.title }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="{% if page.excerpt %}{{ page.excerpt | strip_html | strip_newlines | truncate: 160 }}{% else %}{{ site.description }}{% endif %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.baseurl}}/css/custom.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<!--   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css">
 -->
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- google font -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,800,600,400italic,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- scrollspy -->
  <script type="{{site.baseurl}}/js/scrollspy.js"></script>

  <!-- jquery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

  <!-- custom js -->
  <script src="{{site.baseurl}}/js/nav.js"></script>

  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.url | replace:'index.html','' | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}">
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="{{ site.title }}" href="{{ "/feed.xml" | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url }}" />
</head>
```